# How to number items in for-loop php

Tags: php, for-loop

I have this code that select content from database and loop all, and few items are specify to be different by adding method (type-A and type-B) in database, so now i want to give all type-B numbers like 1,2,3 depending on number of type in database.
I could have do this using the id in database but it not number accordingly so i need just assign new number to list how many of it i have.

```
<?php
        $getReply = $reply_stmt->getAll(); // this from my database
            if(!is_null($getReply)){
            foreach($getReply as $row){
             $name = $row->itemname;
             $method = $row->method;
           }
       if($method == 'type-B'){
          $number = 1;
          $number++;
           echo  $number."B-class<br/>".$name."".$method;
       }else{
          echo  $name."".$method;
        }
     }
?>
```

Now i want to return something like this

> 1 B-class
>
> Peter type-B
>
> John type-A
>
> 2 B-class
>
> Mike type-B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but try to something like this...

```
$getReply = $reply_stmt->getAll(); // this from my database
    if(!is_null($getReply)){
        $number = 1;
        foreach($getReply as $row){
         $name = $row->itemname;
         $method = $row->method;
            if($method == 'type-B'){
               echo  $number." B-class<br/>".$name." ".$method;
               $number++;
            }else{
              echo  $name." ".$method;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: it return 1.1.1 in all Type-B, is not adding increment to the number

Comment: still same result